# How to work a variable inside quotes when the entire code in side a quote

Tags: php, jquery, yii2

I'm wired little bit about this.This is the code what i mean.

```
<div class='pagination-container'>
    <nav>
        <ul class="pagination">

            <li data-page="prev">
                <span>
                    < 
                <span class="sr-only">(current)
                </span></span>
            </li>
            <!--    Here the JS Function Will Add the Rows -->
            <li data-page="next" id="prev">
                <span> > <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>

<?php 
$jquery = '
for (var i = 1; i <= pagenum;) {  
    $(".pagination #prev").before("<li data-page= \' i \' ><span> \' i++ \' <span class=\'sr-only\'>(current)</span></span>\</li>").show();
} 
'; 
$this->registerJs($jquery, View::POS_READY);
?>
```

Here the entire jquery codes are inside a single quoted php variable.The jquery forloop variable "**i**" didn't actually get the list it gets as the text iteself i.so the loop didn't work correctly.
I tried some combinations of quotes here like "<li data-page= "'" + i + "'" > and so on but didn't work

regards.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way -

```
<?php 

$this->registerJs('
   for (var i = 1; i <= pagenum;) {  
       $(".pagination #prev").before("<li data-page= \' i \' ><span> \' i++ \' <span class=\'sr-only\'>'.(current).'</span></span></li>").show();
   }
', View::POS_READY);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using double and single quotes inside your PHP string, the easiest is to use a different string type altogether.

Seeing that you have `$` signs inside your string as well, I would opt for [Nowdoc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc) because it does not parse the content to substitute variables.

For the variable substitution inside the JavaScript string, you can use a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) with the backtick syntax

Your example would end up like this:

```php
<div class='pagination-container'>
    <nav>
        <ul class="pagination">
            <li data-page="prev">
                <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
            </li>
            <!--    Here the JS Function Will Add the Rows -->
            <li data-page="next" id="prev">
                <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
<?php 
$jquery = <<<'JQUERY'
for (var i = 1; i <= pagenum;) {
  $(".pagination #prev").before(`<li data-page="${i}"><span>${i++}</span><span class="sr-only">(current)</span></li>`).show();
} 
JQUERY; 
$this->registerJs($jquery, View::POS_READY);
?>
```

Comment: I tried it,it didn't work in my case.it shows data-page="${i}"  on  inspect ,any way thank you for the answer.

Comment: try '<li data-page="' + i +'"><span>' + i + '</span><span class="sr-only">(current)</span></li>'; i++;